# Iterating Over Arrays of unknown size in member function

Tags: c++

How do I iterate over x and y (without changing it to vector) in the following definition.

```
class MinimumSquareEasy
{

public:

   long minArea(int[] x, int[] y)
   {

     //ITERATION 

    }

};
```

Comment: `minArea` doesn't even have a valid declaration. The square brackets need to come after the variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int x[]` as an argument is the same thing as `int * x` -- you have a pointer, which does not convey any information about the length of an array you might pass in.  Therefore you can't iterate over it as an array, because you have no information to decide when to stop iterating.

You would need to take an additional argument for each array that specifies the length of the array, or use a standard container that conveys length on its own.

Alternatively, you can require that the input arrays are terminated with some sentinel value.  For example, if this sentinel value is -1 then you could loop over both arrays at once using this construct, which will stop iterating when it reaches the sentinel value in *either* array, meaning that you will iterate the number of elements in the smallest of the two arrays:

```
for (; *x != -1 && *y != -1; ++x, ++y) {
    // Use *x and *y
}
```

However, this approach is very much in the style of C and not C++.  Its use in new code should be very discouraged.

Comment: I cannot take any additonal argument.I am confined to this definiton.

Comment: @shubhamr If you cannot change the method signature then your task is impossible.

Comment: Many questions on topcoder ask us to use these type of definitions.There's ought to be some way.

Comment: And what kind of data do you have in there?

Comment: @shubhamr There isn't, unless you *assume* that the input arrays have some particular size, *or* if the arrays contain some "sentinel" value that indicates the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

In SOME **implementations** the allocator **MAY** add the size of allocated buffer just before the actual buffer.
This is sometimes used for the delete[] operator to know how many bytes to free.
**SOME** compilers add a `sizeof(int)` variable with the size.

**BUT** this is just an implementation feature, and is not guaranteed to exist.
One could overload new[] and delete[] operators.
Or the compiler may implement new[] and delete[] with an internal map that uses the address with as a key, therefor you won't have any information about the size by just looking at the buffer.

**It's dangerous, and certainly not something defined in the standard.**

Comment: And a stack-allocated array won't have been allocated with `new[]`, so if someone passes one you would be screwed.